# Java BigInteger цикл while

Tags: java, while, biginteger

Пытаюсь найти произведение квадратов от 1 до 10, но не могу добиться что бы срабатывал счётчик от 1 до 10:

```
        BigInteger n;
    BigInteger cou = BigInteger.valueOf(10);
    BigInteger x = BigInteger.ONE;
    BigInteger summ = BigInteger.ONE;
    while (!x.equals(cou)) {
        n =  x.multiply(x);
        x.add(BigInteger.ONE);
        summ = (summ.multiply(n));
        long zz = summ.longValue();
        System.out.println(zz);
    }
    System.out.println("Произведение квадратов чисел от 1 до 10: "+summ);
```

Постоянно получаю единицу. Прошу помощи.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это связано с тем, что метод `x.add(BigInteger.ONE);` возвращает результат, который вам необходимо присвоить `x`:

`x = x.add(BigInteger.ONE);`

Comment: Слона то я и не заметил. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Забыли присвоить полученное значение переменной :
вместо `x.add(BigInteger.ONE);` надо `x = x.add(BigInteger.ONE);`